# ServiceStack - inheriting all DTO resource in Single Restservice

Tags: c#, servicestack

How to inherit all DTO resource in one service?.

Say for example ,

I Have Resource Class :

```
[RestService("/getstudentname", "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS")] 
public class RestResourcename 
{ 
public string Name { get; set; } 
}

[RestService("/getstudentID", "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS")] 
public class CNextRestResourceid 
{ 
 public string Name { get; set; } 
}
```

I have my Service Class : 
1.How to inherit another DTO Class in this Service ???????? 
2.Do i need to create seperate class for this ?????

```
public class CnextRestService : RestServiceBase<RestResourcename> 
{ 
 public override object OnGet(RestResourcename request) 
 { 
    return request; 
 } 
}
```

Please suggest me on this issues.......

Answer (score 3):

You can implement multiple HTTP Verbs on the same Resource (aka Request) DTO in the same web service, e.g:

```
public class CustomersService : Service
{
    object Get(GetCustomer request){...}
    object Post(CreateCustomer request){...}
    object Put(UpdateCustomer request){...}
    object Delete(DeleteCustomer request){...}
}
```

This allows you to provide multiple implementations for the following HTTP actions:

```
GET   /customers
GET   /customers/1
POST  /customers
PUT   /customers/1
DELETE /customers/1
```

Although if you use SOAP you're limited to 1 RPC method for each web service since SOAP only supports HTTP POST.

The best way to do this is to inherit from **Service** and implement the **Any()** method which will be called regardless of which HTTP Verb or endpoint was used to invoke the service.